# ASP.Net MVC: Render Html.ValidationSummary only if there are errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Html.ValidationSummary() is still being rendered even if the model state is valid.

This example doesn't work:

```
<% if (!this.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{ %>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary()%> 
<% } %>
```

There is still an empty 'ul' tag being rendered.
How do I make it render **only** if the ModelState is not valid?

**EDIT**
Turns out the ModelState is really invalid, but my code does not add any error messages, it's just invalid for no obvious reason.

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password, bool? remember)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Username is required");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "Password is required");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ; // this point is never reached
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the info you provide is correct, then `this.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` is most definitely false. There must be other code here which you don't provide.

Answer (score 2):

The [source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/23011#288016) says that when the model state is valid, the helper returns a null string.  I suspect that your model state is really invalid but that there hasn't been a message added.  Or, it could be that the markup is really coming from something else on your page -- maybe even added with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Check `ClientValidationEnabled` and `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` in app settings. Turning these off if they aren't in use may fix this issue.